# Проблемы с пагинацией в Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pagination

Проблема в следующем. Даю парсеру ссылку на страницу с 10 статьями.

Он переходит по первой ссылке, парсит,... а дальше должен переходить на следующую ссылку в `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('art-postheader')`, но ее не находит (мое предположение что находит, но проблема с `browser.get(url_10)`).

Выдает: URL-ы ЗАКОНЧИЛИСЬ! и завершает программу.
Возможно также что я не совсем правильно выстраиваю цикл либо выход из него.

```
def get_page_data(html):
# Парсим через Selenium Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://мой_сайт.ру/1/1')
spisok = browser.find_elements_by_class_name(
    'art-postheader')
# получаем текущую ссылку на страницу с контентом
# (обычно их по 10 штук на каждой ПРЕД. странице)
for ssilka in spisok:
    try:
        url_10 = ssilka.find_element_by_tag_name(
            'a').get_attribute('href')
    except:
        url_10 = ''
        print('URL-ы ЗАКОНЧИЛИСЬ!')
        browser.quit()
     #   break
    print(url_10)

    # парсим саму страницу        
    browser.get(url_10)
    search_h1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name(
        'art-postheader').text
    search_content = browser.find_elements_by_class_name(
        'clearfix')[7].text

    # ищем комментарии
    try:
        search_comment = browser.find_element_by_id(
            'comments-list').text

        # чистим comment
        search_comment = re.sub(
            '\ on [^\n]*\\n', '\n\n', search_comment)
    except:
        search_comment = '\n\n\n'
    print('закончили парсить комментарии')
   # break  # прерываем внутренний цикл
```

Подскажите где ошибся.

Итак. `print(spisok)` выводит список элементов:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-1")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-2")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-3")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-4")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-5")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-6")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-7")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-8")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-9")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d0448b3fa2b9c039ebf4f409b28d9ddd", element="0.8163198014547386-10")>]
```

Comment: Так а в смысле? Вы находите ОДИН элемент в переменной `url_10` и потом пытаетесь по одному элементу пройтись ЦИКЛОМ?

Comment: Или у вас в теге `href` 10 ссылок, а не одна?

Comment: spisok = browser.find_elements_by_class_name(
        'art-postheader') имеет 10 ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ (урлов). Они там точно есть это я проверил. url_10 принимает их по очереди. Когда я вырезаю второй цикл (оставляя break) url_10 ПОЛУЧАЕТ следующий УРЛ (и так все 10 и выводит их в консоли). Однако если во втором цикле снова вставить browser.get(url_10) то он НЕ ВИДИТ 2-й и последующий урлы (URL-ы ЗАКОНЧИЛИСЬ!).

Answer (score 0):

В первом цикле, вы присваиваете переменной `url_10` ОДИН элемент найденный по `find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')`.

```
for ssilka in spisok:
    url_10 = ssilka.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    for ssilka in url_10:
        browser.get(url_10)
```

А потом запускаете вложенный (второй) цикл `for ssilka in url_10:` по переменной `url_10` с одним элементом.

У вас второй цикл лишний.

```
for ssilka in spisok:
    url_10 = ssilka.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(url_10)
    browser.get(url_10)
```

Comment: Здесь вы правы, можно и без второго цикла, однако это к сожалению не ришило проблемы с получением следующего урла по очереди и ПЕРЕХОДУ на него. Возможно проблема с browser.get(url_10) - можно ли заставить Селениум перейти по ссылке как-то иначе?

Comment: Убрал цикл (for ssilka in url_10:), убрал break этого цикла. Теперь возникает ошибка: Возникло исключение: urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы с .get(). Вероятно есть проблема с вашим кодом. Давайте начнём с базы. Давайте посмотрим, что у вас в `spisok`

Comment: Добавил вывод spisok выше, убрал второй цикл.

Comment: Проблема действительно есть. Если убираю все что ниже print(url_10) то получаю чистые урлы 10 шт.

Comment: А вы попробовали ваш цикл заменить на тот, что я предложил? Браузер переходит по ссылкам? Можно перед `browser.get(url_10)` поставить `print(url_10)` что-бы быть уверенным что url в нормальном виде

Comment: Да, попробовал. Сделал также как вы указали выше, после первого перехода по ссылке и сохранения контента пишет URL-ы ЗАКОНЧИЛИСЬ!

Comment: @bbmaster вы можете использовать мой код как есть? не дополняя его блоками try, и вообще, после переменных просто сделать 4 строки предложенного мною кода. Добавил print(url_10), что бы видеть что передаётся в переменную. Дополните свой вопрос скриншотом того, что вывела консоль